# Dealing with infinite loops

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn PHP programming through trial, error and lots and lots of practice.
I've been working on a directory bases image gallery for the last few days and it seems to work fine. I can upload pictures and create new albums. Plus whenever I see a full size picture I have links to the previous and next pictures in the directory.

Now this is where I ran into problems. Once you got to the end of the directory the code would start an infinite loop while it searches for the next file, which isn't there.

So I altered my code and it now looks something like this:

```
$x = 1;
$dir = opendir($base.'/'.$get_album);
while ((($file = readdir($dir)) !== FALSE) && ($x == 1)) {
  while ($img < $file) {
    $img++;
    $image_exists = file_exists($base.'/'.$get_album.'/'.$img);
    if ($image_exists) {
      echo "<a href='member.php?album=$get_album&imgID=$img'>
              <img src='$base/$get_album/$img' width='70' align='right'>
            </a>";
      break;
    }
    $x++;
  }
}
```

This works when I get to the last picture in the directory. So I thought I'd do the same for when I get to the first picture and just invert the operators like so:

```
$x = 1;
$dir = opendir($base.'/'.$get_album);
while ((($file = readdir($dir)) !== FALSE) && ($x == 1)) {
  while ($img > $file) {
    $img--;
    $image_exists = file_exists($base.'/'.$get_album.'/'.$img);
    if ($image_exists) {
      echo "<a href='member.php?album=$get_album&imgID=$img'>
              <img src='$base/$get_album/$img' width='70' align='right'>
            </a>";
      break;
    }
    $x++;
  }
}
```

This however DOES NOT work. I can't understand why that would be the case and I've tried to change things around a few dozen times but I cant seem to make it stop looping.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help (and for reading through all this).

Comment: where do you set the initial value for `$img` (before entering the while loops) ???

Comment: *Please* indent your code properly, and try not to over use parens and braces - after editing your code into something uniform, it becomes apparent that the only thing you have changed between versions is that `$img++` has become `$img--`...

Comment: I also changed "while ($img < $file)" to "while ($img > $file)". I'll try to improve the way I post code next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could likely be related to the fact that readdir returns a string, and you are treating it as if you know its a number. You might find that it is returning you something at the start or end, such as the parent directory '..' as a string or the current directory as a string '.'.

If you want to iterate over the directories, you should check that the return value from readdir is not '.' or '..' specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Please use a better format to your code (it's really painful read it), for instance, in netbeans you can use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to format automatically.

I want address your attention to this line:

```
$image_exists= file_exists($base.'/'.$get_album.'/'.$img);
```

That is a possible source of errors. If only `$base.'/'.$get_album.'/'` exists then:

```
$image_exists= file_exists($base.'/'.$get_album.'/'.$img); // is true even if $img is empty!!!
```

---

But  moreover:

What is `$img`? You treat it as a number when do `$img++` and then as a string. That is not good for your health.

A good start it should be initialize your vars at the beginning of your code. And then use them in consonance.

Comment: $img is the GET variable for the image ID. It is a number because images are renamed using the time function. $file is also the name of images but comes from the readdir function instead. The page will display the image that is equal to the $img, then loop $img through the available $file's till it finds a previous and a later image to display. I thought this process up myself so if I could have made it more easily I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: @spacitron Great! You will learn very fast and fine with the help of this stunning community. Welcome...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something fundamentally wrong with the design, you are comparing `$img`, an uninitialized integer, to `$file`, a string.

It also seems needlessly complicated, as you are reading files from a directory, then check if they exist and break out of your loop if they do.

Perhaps with a clear view of the directory structure and what you are trying to do, I could provide a more detailed answer, but I think you need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: File names are chosen by using the time function. So while it's a string it is a string of numbers. $img is set to GET the image id (which is also a filename). So I am able to compare the  2. If it is needlessly complicated I'm open to suggestion on way to improve it. I'm having a hard time to keep my code simple and I don't know where to find info out there on the topic.